# Conversion from child class to parent for templated function pointer

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, function-pointers

Here is a problem involving inheritance, template classes and function pointers. I'm developing a modular tool, here is a minimal depiction of it.

I have a generic base class that I need to be as general as possible (for reasons unspecified here):

```
// base class
class Base {
public:
    virtual void assess( ) = 0;
};
```

Then I have a more specialized derived class, that I define as a template:

```
// derived template class
template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base
{
protected:
    T mValue;
public:
    void assess( );
    T value( ) { return mValue; }
};

// function specialization here
template<>
inline void Derived<int>::assess( )
{
    mValue = 3;
}
```

Some parts are specialized, like the `assess()` function, as shown above.

Then I have an extra layer of inheritance. The main idea is to have a general `assess()` function that involves a function pointer with a `Base` object as argument.

```
// class specialization for special evaluation through function pointers
template <typename T>
class DerivedFuncPtr : public Derived<T> {
protected:
    T (*mFuncPtr)( Base& );
    Base *mFuncVar;
public:
    DerivedFuncPtr<T>( T (*f)(Base&), Base& variable )
    {
        mFuncPtr = f;
        mFuncVar = variable;
    }
    void assess( )
    {
        mFuncVar->assess();
        this->mValue = (*mFuncPtr)(*mFuncVar);
    }
};
```

OK, the problem is how to use it. Main source looks like this:

```
int squared( Derived<int>& );
int squared( Derived<int>& d )
{
    int val = d.value();
    return val*val;
}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Derived<int> object;
    object.assess();
    cout << object.value() << "\n" ;

    DerivedFuncPtr<int> objectFP( squared, object ); // (*)

    return 0;
}
```

I get an error at compilation on line `(*)`

```
Candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'int (Derived<int> &)' to 'int (*)(Base &)' for 1st argument
```

Will I be forced to encapsulate the function pointer into a templated `U (*)(Base&)` class or am I missing something obvious here?

For the sake of esthetics and because I am really not familiar with most recent C++ evolutions, I'd prefer not to use `boost` libraries or C++11, but well, if it can't be helped...
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
DerivedFuncPtr<T>( T (*f)(Base&), Base& variable )
```

The first argument to your constructor is a pointer to a function that takes a `Base&` as an argument (and returns a `T`). That `Base&` argument to the function pointer doesn't match the argument to `squared`, which takes a `Derived<int>&`.

One way to fix this is to make `DerivedFuncPtr` a class template that take two template arguments, one the `typename T` you already have, and the other, some other typename that will replace the uses of `Base` in your data members and constructor.

BTW, you also get an error on `mFuncVar = variable;` in that constructor. `mFuncVar` is a pointer, `variable` is a reference.

Comment: Thank you. I thought that this conversion could go through because `Derived<int>` is a child from `Base`. In the same class, I take advantage of this inheritance to define a `std::vector<Base*>` within `Derived`, and conversion works. I'm working on your fix suggestion.

Comment: @motjordet - Casting from a derived class pointer to a base class pointer is a "standard conversion" (clause 4 of the standard). It's an automatic conversion; no cast is needed. This is why you can have a vector of pointers to your base class. Casting from a base class pointer to a derived class pointer is a different story. It's not automatic; a cast is required. Your `squared` cannot match `T (*)( Base&)` because `squared` has a different signature.

Comment: Got it. I found a workaround that does the trick, using `static_cast` conversion within the body of `squared`:
    `int squared( Base& d )
    {
        Derived<int>& dconv = static_cast< Derived<int> &>(d);
        int val = dconv.value();
        return val*val;
    }`
Requires for the developer to be careful, but what do you think of it otherwise, @DavidHammen ?